# iPhone, UINavigationController and UITabBar how to present a modal dialog regardless of the selected tab?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UINavigationController and a UITabBar within the application. Each ViewController within the tabbar has its own UINavigationController.

**I would like to be able to present a modal dialog to the user (an alert/reminder/legal/join mailing list) kind of action regardless of the currently selected tab.**

Right now I have one of my UIViewControllers handle the act of presenting the dialog, but the user would not see it, unless the tab has been selected.

How would I go about solving such a problem? Storyboards come to mind, but my project is far too deep to rewrite it for storyboards in its current state.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could present it on the UITabBarController.

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:animated:];
```

Answer (score 0):

...or you can easily **subclass UIAlertView**/create a **category** to show a custom modal view when you want, simply calling

```
UIAlertView *alert = 
  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                             message:@"" 
                            delegate:nil 
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"" 
                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert showCustom]; // <---- FROM CATEGORY

[alert release];
```

Here an example: http://goo.gl/7jaE8